# need to overlay text on top of the image and make the text follow it , as the picture dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, css

The text that should be on the picture and follow it

```
<h1>Enter</h1>
```

the picture itself

[image]

I was told to try "position relative" but nothing worked does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: The picture is an animated GIF?

Comment: The text that should be on the picture and follow it? what does that mean?

Comment: @Oskar Grosser , Yes

Comment: @DCR , picture is dymanic GIF , it changes his position so i want to put text on this GIF with 'position : absolute' and make it follow picture as well

Comment: It would be easier to have two images instead of a gif

Comment: @KonradLinkowski , and how do i implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Animations

### Syncing to animated images

Quickly skimming through the spec I didn't find anything to whether animated images (e.g. animated GIFs) should be in sync with CSS. Therefore I presume that **animated images may or may not be in sync**, depending on the implementation.

Not only is this (presumably) not defined, images' actual presentation may be deferred. We *can* specify `sync`, `async` or `auto` (default) for attribute [`decoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-decoding), but that is just a hint which the browser *may not* honour.

This means while we can *try* to sync CSS with animated images, this may not actually work due to technical reasons.

Here is my approach to getting the CSS animation to sync with the animated image. Note that while it may *look* synchronous for the first 1 or 2 cycles, it quickly gets out of sync due to me being off by a tiny bit:

```css
@keyframes gif-anim {
  0% {top: 40%}
  50% {top: 30%} 
}

.wrapper {position: relative}
.wrapper img {width: 100%}
.wrapper h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: .715s normal .14s gif-anim infinite backwards steps(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/I62VF.gif>
  <h1>Enter</h1>
</div>
```

### Syncing with [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations)

If we had the individual images that make up the animated image, we could synchronize it with CSS [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

It is significantly easier to synchronize if the frames are evenly spaced across the animation cycle. Example:

```css
@keyframes img-anim {
  0% {background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200)}
  50% {background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/200)}
}
@keyframes text-anim {
  0% {left: 0%}
  50% {left: 50%}
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200);
  animation: img-anim 1s infinite steps(1);
}
.wrapper>h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: text-anim 1s infinite steps(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Enter</h1>
</div>
```